# sync adapter not working in android l

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

whenever i login into the app ,I am starting sync adapter.It will sync data for every 12 hours.Right now  it is working fine in android kitkat and lower versions but when i login into my app and current os android lollipop,it is crashing please help me

error Log:

```
 12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[Sync service]
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000): Process: com.sample.example, PID: 10000
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error unparceling Bundle
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000):    at android.content.ContentResolver.validateSyncExtrasBundle(ContentResolver.java:1835)
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000):    at android.content.SyncRequest$Builder.build(SyncRequest.java:490)
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000):    at com.sample.example.BeatsSyncAdapter.configurePeriodicSync(SampleSyncAdapter.java:129)
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000):    at com.sample.example.sync.BeatsSyncAdapter.onAccountCreated(SampleSyncAdapter.java:177)
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000):    at com.sample.example.sync.BeatsSyncAdapter.getSyncAccount(SampleSyncAdapter.java:168)
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000):    at com.sample.example.sync.BeatsSyncAdapter.initializeSyncAdapter(SampleSyncAdapter.java:190)
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000):    at com.sample.example.service.SampleSyncService.onHandleIntent(SampleSyncService.java:22)
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Set android.os.Bundle.keySet()' on a null object reference
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000):    at android.content.ContentResolver.validateSyncExtrasBundle(ContentResolver.java:1819)
    12-03 10:56:10.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10000):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: This is not a duplicated question, the reason for the nullpointer here is that the SyncRequest have no extra Bundle set when created! add a ".setExtras(new Bundle())" before calling build();